# In wxpython, how can I drag a frame while having it play a GIF animation

Tags: animation, wxpython, draggable, gif

I'm using wxpython-Phoenix 3.0.3 version for this.

I would like to make a draggable image which plays a GIF Animation.
The function works fine when I comment out the animation part, but it doesn't work when the animation is played.
How can I make them work together?

```
import wx
from wx.adv import AnimationCtrl


class Yukari(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.closeWindow)

        self.animation = AnimationCtrl(self)
        self.animation.LoadFile('Resized_Yuzuki-Yukari.gif')
        self.animation.Play()

        self.SetSize((497, 720))
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.Show()

    def OnMouse(self, event):

        if not event.Dragging():
            self._dragPos = None
            pass
        if not self._dragPos:
            self._dragPos = event.GetPosition()
        else:
            pos = event.GetPosition()
            displacement = self._dragPos - pos
            print(displacement)
            self.SetPosition(self.GetPosition() - displacement)

    def closeWindow(self, event):
        key_code = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key_code == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.Destroy()
        event.Skip()


app = wx.App()
frame = Yukari(None, -1, 'Yuzuki Yukari')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on Linux mate 17, python 2.7, wx.python ('2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode)', using `from wx.animate import AnimationCtrl`.
When you say "but it doesn't work when the animation is played", it what way doesn't it work and when you state "draggable image" do you mean that the image is "draggable" within the frame or that the frame is draggable?
Plus I believe that you need to put the item within something like a wx.panel() to be able to activate the event motion i.e.

```
self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
self.panel1.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)
self.panel1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.closeWindow)

self.animation = AnimationCtrl(self.panel1)
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, "wx.animate import AnimationCtrl" doesn't work for Phoenix version. And what i meant for draggable image is, the frame itself is not draggable.
yeah i will try using panel instead of frame thanks for the advice!